# #1064 - MySQL Error

Tags: mysql, phpbb

```
CREATE TABLE  `phpbb_acl_groups` (

 `group_id` MEDIUMINT( 8 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
 `forum_id` MEDIUMINT( 8 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
 `auth_option_id` MEDIUMINT( 8 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
 `auth_role_id` MEDIUMINT( 8 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
 `auth_setting` TINYINT( 2 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
KEY  `group_id` (  `group_id` ) ,
KEY  `auth_opt_id` (  `auth_option_id` ) ,
KEY  `auth_role_id` (  `auth_role_id` )
) TYPE = MYISAM ;
```

MySQL meldet: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'TYPE=MyISAM' at line 10

Answer (score 0):

`TYPE = MYISAM ;`  has been depreciated and you should be using `engine` instead

`engine = MYISAM`